# Set Current culture in url when application starts or navigates to home page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on a small web application (Razor Pages) and I have added localization to it. The problem I have now is the following:

When application loads first time or when user presses home button `(<a href="/"</a>)`, the url  in the browser is this:

`https://localhost/`

and when I press  a link `(<a asp-page="/login"></a>)` it navigates me to `https://localhost/login` instead of `https://localhost/{currentCulture}/login`

and for this reason, I want to it to be something like this:

`https://localhost/{currentCulture}/`

For example, for english --> `https://localhost/en/`

I have already set default current culture and it is applied when application starts but it is not written in the url.

I have followed this tutorial to add localization to my app : http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application

**Update:**

When User presses home button I did this:`<a href="/@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name"></a>` and it works.

Comment: What do you want to say by {currentCulutre} ?

Comment: `http://localhost/en/` for english, for example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how good solution it is, but you can solve this problem so:

Create a class and implement `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite.IRule`:

```
public class FirstLoadRewriteRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        if(request.Path == "/")  
        {
            request.Path = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString($"/{culture.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

In your app `request.Path == "/"` will be true only when app loads first time (when you press home, request.path is "/en" {for English}). So, default culture name will be added to the url. You will not see it in url when app loads, but when you press `(<a asp-page="/login"></a>)`, you will see that you are redirected to `https://localhost/en/login`.

You have to register this rule in `startup.cs` in `Configure` method:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().Add(new FirstLoadRewriteRule());
app.UseRewriter(options);
```